# not correctly traversing through DOM in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

The simplified code below is supposed to add a value in cell-row 2-colum 2 in a table depending on the value selected in row 1 colum 2 of this table. The (jquery) handler for this writing is triggered correctly (tested by console), but writing to the div element (using html() ) does not work, and I strongly suspect I dont traverse through the DOM correctly. I tried a few options (see comments) but none of them works. Where do I go wrong?

```
<table border="1"> <!--table ProductMain with only 1 row en 2 cells -->
    <!--table ProductMain; cell r1c1-->
    <tr>
        <td>cell r1c1</td> 

        <!--table ProductMain; cell r1c2-->
        <td>
            <select  class="eprodtype" name="ecorp_productid4"> 
                <option selected="selected" value="" ></option>
                <option  value="val1" > val1</option>
                <option  value="val2" > val2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <!--table ProductMain; cell r2c1; -->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border ='1'>
                <tr class="r2"> <td> aval1 </td> <td> aval2 </td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>

        <!--table ProductMain; cell r2c2;-->
        <td class="r2c2">
            <div class="ecorpproductwrapper"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("change", ".eprodtype", function() {
        var selectedvalue = $( this ).val();  
        console.log("SELECT selectedvalue "+selectedvalue);

        //NONE OF THE FOLLOWING OPTIONS WORK
        //$(this).parent().children("td.r2c2").children("div.ecorpproductwrapper").html("<p> Chosen: " + selectedvalue + "</p>");
        //$(this).parent().children("tr.r2").children("td.r2c2").children("div.ecorpproductwrapper").html("<p> Chosen: " + selectedvalue + "</p>");
        $(this).parent().parent().find("div.ecorpproductwrapper").html("<p> Chosen: " + selectedvalue + "</p>");
        //$(this).parent().children("div.ecorpproductwrapper").html("<p> Chosen: " + selectedvalue + "</p>");
    });
}); //$(document).ready
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed one more `parent` call to go up to the `table`. However, you can clean the code by using `closest` instead to get the `table`, then `find` within that:

```
$(this).closest('table').find("div.ecorpproductwrapper").html("<p>Chosen: " + selectedvalue + "</p>");
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eFW4k/)